# .NET Core, SignalR 2 serialization (DateTime)

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

How configure datetime format serialization in SignalR 2 (2.2.1)

Because output json with datetime can be with UTC and without UTC in one response

"dateTime":"2017-02-17T20:27:04.9225787+02:00"

"dateTime":"2017-02-17T20:00:10.1540101"

Comment: Send it as string and parse accordingly

Comment: You have options to convert to string and parse within Javascript, but in my experience it is easier to just convert to a Unix Timestamp and then parse that in Javascript, which is supported by all good date libraries, eg moment.js This way there are no hidden configurations or specific formatting/parsing on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works

```cs
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";
            options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        });

        services.AddSingleton(_ => new JsonSerializer {
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        });
```